# How to insantiate a class after rotating the device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I have a fragment which runs camera in it. and then in the main activity, I instantiate the class by passing the context to it

```
      Camera_play fragment1 = new Camera_play(this);
```

I have other fragments which play images and videos.

I rotate the device after 10 seconds to landscape mode and I need all the fragments to keep playing .

```
          Timer timer = new Timer();
          TimerTask action = new TimerTask() {


             public void run() 
             {

                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                      public void run(){
                 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                      }

                 });    
                      }

            };


            timer.schedule(action, 10000);
```

I handle the objects as follows :

```
   if(savedInstanceState == null)
     {
      frg1 = new Camera_play(this);
      frg2 = new play_video();
     android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager= getSupportFragmentManager();
     transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
     transaction.add(R.id.video, frg1,"frag1");
      transaction.add(R.id.camera, frg2,"frag2");
      transaction.commit();
     }
  else
   {
      **frg1 = new Camera_play(this);** ?????
      frg2 = (play_video) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag2");
   }
```

This works fine for the video but the app crashes for the video stating the instantation failed and the class msut have an empty constructor.

How do I make the camera to continue playing after I rotate the device?

Comment: Can we see your Logcat please?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.stresstest/com.example.stresstest.MainActivity}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.stresstest.Camera_play: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public